# Loading referenced dll at runtime

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, plugins, reference, system.reflection

I've been trying to develop a plugin system for a site I'm working on. I've got it working fine apart from in scenario. When the plugin itself has a dependent dll.

The main site is just a simple MVC site which references a few projects which contain things like a folder watcher for new plugins that are dropped in, the plugin interface, the plugin description readers, controller factory etc. When the site loads it looks into the plugins directory within the main MVC site and loads each dll which uses the IPlugin interface. When the plugin is initialised it adds its own routes.

This all works fine if the plugin itself is one MVC site project. The issues occur when the plugin has a reference to something not referenced in the main MVC site (so say the plugins own business layer project). The site loads fine but when you navigation to '/Admin' which is the plugin then I get the following error : -

Could not load file or assembly 'AdminPlugin.Common, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

I can get this error to go if I also reference this project from the main MVC site however as this is meant to be a plugin system that isn't an option.

I've uploaded the solution to GitHub as it's too much to paste in. I've done the usual of loading the assembly, getting the type then doing ActiveInstance etc and that is done in the Main MVC site. Should I be doing that in the plugin? Does anyone know how to correct this option.

The current solution in GitHub is in the state of giving the error. The TestWebsite project has a folder called 'Plugins' which the plugin 'AdminPlugin.Web' builds to a folder called 'AdminPlugin' within the 'Plugins' folder. You would need to rebuild the AdminPlugin.Web if you change the code at all in the plugin. It should just rebuild fine.

I really hope someone can help with this as it is really annoying now :).

GitHub - https://github.com/Dilvid/MVCPluginExample

Comment: Asking people to download your github project and install and run it, and then correct your code is likely a bit much for SO. I'd start by thinking about security. How can you ensure a plugin doesn't `format c:` which btw would be best case scenario since at least you'd know. Alternatively go look at how Umbraco or nopCommerce do it.

Comment: I'm not asking people to download my code and run it. If you actually read my post I've said I've put it on GitHub as too big to paste it in. To get the context of what is going on in multiple projects in multiple classes by pasting snippets wouldn't work. Also again, read the post!! The plugin system works apart from the plugins dependencies. Which is what I asked for HELP AND GUIDANCE with, not to fix my code. People like you is why I can't stand stack overflow anymore, far too interested in the 'I've answered this many posts' than actually wanting to properly help people.

Comment: I did read your post especially this bit `You would need to rebuild the AdminPlugin.Web if you change the code at all in the plugin. It should just rebuild fine` . Sounds like download and run to me. Either way if I've misunderstood there's no need to rant. I appreciate the frustration of coding sometimes but just chill out, someone else may help you but honestly check out the guidance for asking questions as I think it falls outside the scope. And after 6 years or so here and only 5k rep I'm hardly chasing it so don't let me scare you away. All the best.

Comment: Sorry for ranting. Just a bad day lol. I've literally only put the GitHub stuff on as its so hard to explain without showing people. Thought even if they browsed the code it may help. Sorry again for ranting.